# Get the current project directory from flutter integration test

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to get the current project directory in flutter integration test? This is a basic test setup as an example.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:ivori/main.dart' as app;
import 'package:glob/glob.dart';

void main() {
  // This line enables the extension.
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();

  print("Where the working directory? ${Directory.current}");
  print("What's under the current directory? ${Glob("*").listSync()}");

  // Call the `main()` function of the app, or call `runApp` with
  // any widget you are interested in testing.
  app.main();
}
```

Both of the middle two added lines `Directory.current` and `Glob("*").listSync()` are attempts to check/show the current working directory. The output from the above is:

```
$ flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart        
Changing current working directory to: /Users/yuchen/Documents/MyDemoApp
Using device iPhone SE (2nd generation).
Starting application: test_driver/app.dart
...
...
...
flutter: Where the working directory? Directory: '/'
flutter: What's under the current directory? [Directory: './home', Directory: './usr', File: './.DS_Store', Directory: './bin', Directory: './sbin', File: './.file',
Directory: './etc', Directory: './var', Directory: './Library', Directory: './System', Link: './.VolumeIcon.icns', Directory: './.fseventsd', Directory: './private',
Directory: './.vol', Directory: './Users', Directory: './Applications', Directory: './opt', Directory: './dev', Directory: './Volumes', Directory: './tmp', Directory:
'./cores']
```

Not hard to see, the working directory is actually set to the root folder of the computer. Is there a way to get to the current project directory or src directory somehow?

---

The motivation behind this is to have some test data that will be used during the test but not in the app bundle. There are some discussions (fixes and work rounds) about unit tests in this long thread https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12999. However,  it doesn't seem to have a solution for integration tests.

Comment: From this [example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files#complete-example), `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();` might be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the link! But `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` is for the app's document folder (for data generated by the app), and the example is for mocking that for testing. However, what I am looking for is a way to use data outside of the app for testing purposes. From the link that you shared, imagine if I want to test if the app document folder has a `blah.data` file, we can mock it via the `MethodChannel` mansion there, but how do I store this piece of `blah.data`? I know it is on my file system on the host machine, but it is tricky to get the relative path for it.

Comment: yes relative path is tricky to get.

Comment: @Yuchen, did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @BenjaminLee, no, if you ever figured it out, would be nice if you can share it here!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used [ext_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage) to access the device's storage. The path_provider plugin seems to only able to access the app's directory.

Here's a sample of fetching the storage path for Downloads.

```dart
/// Get storage path for Downloads
/// https://pub.dev/documentation/ext_storage/latest/
Future<String> _getPath() {
  return ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
      ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The motivation behind this is to have some test data that will be used during the test but not in the app bundle.

What you want to do is not possible in flutter integration tests by design: android emulators and physical devices will have separate file systems, thus any file you want to access during an integration test should be added into the application bundle.

This isn't true for iOS simulators however, because an iOS simulator basically shares it's file system with the host machine.
If you're happy with your tests only working on iOS simulators you can pass the project root via `flutter test integration_test --dart-define=projectRoot=$(pwd)` — this value can later be obtained in the test like this — `const projectRoot = String.fromEnvironment('projectRoot')`.

Now, if you want fully functional flutter integration tests, the only way around this limitation is to either retrieve the needed data via network when the test starts or add it into the application bundle.